# Facebook Graph API - Page Post Location

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the place for a page post?

The [Graph API documentation for a post object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post) says there is a place field that has place id, name, longitude, latitude, etc.

Here are the steps I followed to test this:

- In Facebook UI, I posted to my page with the location enabled
- Using Graph API, I read page posts (https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/feed?access_token={TOKEN}&since={STARTDATE}&until={ENDDATE})
- I observed that the JSON response contained my post and no place field was present.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but you can get location information from using the `?fields=place` option when querying the specific post details.

Here is the code I'm using to fetch posts and their location from a Facebook Page. You can replace `/posts` with `/feed` for your example

```
FB.api('/{PAGE_ID}/posts', function(response) {
  if (!response.error) {
    var posts = response.data;
    for (i = 0; i < posts.length; i++)
    {
      var post = posts[i];
      FB.api('/' + post.id + '?fields=place', function(response) {
        if (!response.error && response.place) {
          post.place = response.place;
        }
        console.log(post);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use this method with `?fields=attachments` to get any pictures or videos attached to the post.

Hope this helps 19 months later :]